# Wordpress plugin using Jquery broken in Webkit browsers after update

Tags: jquery, wordpress, webkit, galleria

After updating to Wordpress 3.2.1 my photo gallery plugin, *Photo Galleria*, has now broken in Webkit browsers.

[Here is an example page](http://www.uwesu.net/archaos/wordpress/posts/613) with a gallery, which works in IE8 & FF, but not Webkit browsers.

The Javascript console in Chrome states this

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( [galleria.works.js.55]

Uncaught Error: Fatal error: No theme found. [galleria.js:77]
```

'works' is the name of a custom theme I made for *Photo Galleria*, which I mainly adapted from other Galleria themes.

It seems the theme attempts to load before the plugin, which is suggested by the "No theme found" error, but seeing it works fine in other browsers, is this the real problem?

I have been going in circles with regard to how Webkit browsers load Jquery and other javascript, and I haven't cracked it yet. My javascript knowledge is basic at best, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: The link above may not work after a while as we are moving hosts soon.

Comment: Would you mind posting a link to the source of the theme you modified to make your custom theme?

Comment: I can't find the original any more, probably because I cobbled it together from a number of sources. I believe it is to do with the counter, which used to appear on previous versions but now does not.

Comment: It looks like there might be some issues with the works javascript file.  The browsers that are working correctly may be a little more tolerant.  Do you have a link to any theme javascript file that I could take a look at?

Comment: [Classic Theme](http://galleria.aino.se/themes/classic/) (a similar setup, note counter bottom left - [Pastbin link to js](http://pastebin.com/j2G5Bm1G)

Comment: Where does Galleria get defined?  I am trying to recreate the issue, but keep getting an error "Galleria is undefined".  I can't find in your code where it is defined.

Comment: [Galleria.js](http://www.uwesu.net/archaos/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/photo-galleria/galleria.js?ver=3.2.1) is linked to in the header, below Jquery.

Comment: Right so it is defiantly my theme that is causing the problems. If you can figure out what i've done wrong with [this](http://www.uwesu.net/archaos/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/photo-galleria/themes/works/galleria.works.js) that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to go ahead and start an answer instead of continuing to comment.

For starters, inside the init function you have a block of code that looks like the following:

```
counter: function () {
     return c.showing_image.replace(/\%s/, a.getIndex() + 1).replace(/\%s/, a.getDataLength())
}
```

Try commenting that out and see if you can get it to run.  You are trying to insert a property in the middle of the function and that is not legal syntax.  Your counter may not show up, but getting it to load up is the first step.

Comment: It's working great! Sometimes being so close to a problem for hours on end really doesn't help. Thanks for taking a look Tim, I should be able to sort out the rest from here.